# Python- Problem with data merge of 2 tables in sqlite3

Tags: python

I have tables in the database: customers [] and accounts [].
There is an accounts table in the database. This table has a foreign key (owner field) that should point to a specific customer (relationship customers.id = accounts.owner).

I would like to save the accounts from the list in the database in such a way that the owners of the next accounts are the next customers from the previous list (the relation should be kept), that is: (relation customers.id = accounts.owner). Here is my code:

```
with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE) as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    results = cursor.execute('select id from customers')
    result = results.fetchone()
    cursor_2 = connection.cursor()
    
    cursor_2.row_factory=sqlite3.Row
    i = 0
    while result:
            result2 = cursor_2.execute('insert into accounts (number, owner) values (?,?)', (accounts[i], result[0]))
            result = results.fetchone()
            i += 1
    for row in cursor_2.execute(SQL_SELECT):
        print(dict(row))
```

**Unfortunately, when I select the result, I get an error:**

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-69ff9849bb7a> in <module>
     66     i = 0
     67     while result:
---> 68             result2 = cursor_2.execute('insert into accounts (number, owner) values (?,?)', (accounts[i], result[0]))
     69             result = results.fetchone()
     70             i += 2

IndexError: **list index out of range**
```

I have a request to indicate what is wrong here

Comment: looks like `accounts` is empty

Comment: the accounts table has 100 records, just like the customers table

Comment: before `while result:` DO `print(len(accounts))` - what do you get?

Comment: I got100 records